# notification overlapping and bugged

Tags: javascript, html

I created notification system and it works fine but if you do it for few times it doesn't create another one it just overlaps and text removed just notification.

How can I make it like so it will create another notification just below every notification if one exits?

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    ShowNotif(event.data);
});

function ShowNotif(data) {
    if (data.type === 'adm') {
       launch_admin(data);
    } 
}

function launch_admin(data) {
    var x = document.getElementById("toast")
    x.className = "show";
    document.getElementById("image").src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/196/196759.svg";
    document.getElementById("toast").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(227, 185, 70, 0.8)";
    document.getElementById("toast").style.borderRadius = "25px"
    document.getElementById("toast").style.borderStyle = "none"
    document.getElementById("desc").style.color = "#d43f3f"
    setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("desc").textContent  = data.text; }, 600);
    setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("desc").textContent  = ""; }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 5000);
}


<div id="toast">
                <img id="image" alt="W3Schools" src="" style="width:50px;height:50px;float:left;padding-top:6px;padding-bottom:6px;box-sizing:border-box;">
                <div id="desc"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Currently, you're selecting an existing DOM element, and reusing it for all your notifications. That's why only the last notification shows. You need to dynamically create and remove elements from the DOM. ...or don't reinvent the wheel and use one of the many ready-made notifications libraries (toasts etc.) like [Toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr)

Comment: can u help me like how can i create dynamically noitificaions like every notificaion have unique id

Comment: Sure, [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=js+how+to+dynamically+create+and+remove+dom+elements) are PLENTY of resources and tutorials about how to achieve this  :)

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate a self-closing BR tag at the end of each notification by adding it directly at the end of the text to make them change lines like this:

```
('My Notification text here or in some variable') + "</br>";
```

Comment: Then there is no room for your text in the zone where you make it appear, so you can either replace it completely each time in the same object, or make a bigger(taller maybe?) div container for your notifications. Or try <br> apparently it no longer require a slash. And try giving to your notification container the css3 style overflow: auto;